# Round Robin for module loadbalance not working

Tags: node.js

I am using the loadbalance module. It works fine for randomEngine but does not work for RoundRobinEngine. Can someone help me as to where the issue is Code :-

```js
const loadbalance = require('loadbalance');
const engine = loadbalance.roundRobin([
  { object: 'a', weight: 2 },
  { object: 'b', weight: 1 }
]);
const pick = engine.pick();
console.log(pick);
```

In the above case i am getting output as 'a' everytime. It does not throw output 'b'. Can someone help me out in this

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `weight` param to `2` for the `a` entry. So the `roundRobin` will pick `a` twice as often as `b`. If you will put more `.pick()` calls, you will see how it works:

```
const loadbalance = require('loadbalance');
const engine = loadbalance.roundRobin([
  { object: 'a', weight: 2 },
  { object: 'b', weight: 1 }
]);
let pick = engine.pick();
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(pick);
  pick = engine.pick();
}
```

and the output will be:

```
a
a
b
a
a
b
```

Se live demo: https://repl.it/repls/UntimelyDelayedScope

Answer (score 0):

`pick` pick is a constance, when you print out `pick` value it is the same in everywhere.

Just call `engine.pick()` when you want to choose next object with your rule.

In example, I all `.pick` with 6 times:

```
const loadbalance = require('loadbalance');
const engine = loadbalance.roundRobin([
  { object: 'a', weight: 2 },
  { object: 'b', weight: 1 }
]);

//const pick = engine.pick();

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(engine.pick());
}

// 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'
```